# How long does a clean install of Lion take?

Tags: macos, install

How long should I expect it to take to do a clean install of Lion on an already-formatted disk? I'm using a [mid-2010 15" MacBook Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=MacBook_Pro&oldid=441784309#Technical_specifications_2) with an i7 and a 5,400RPM 500GB hard drive.

(I ask because I think my hard drive is in bad condition, and the installation seems like it's taking too long.)

Comment: Since you install on a clean drive, is it possibly *downloading* the installer?

Comment: Exactly. The installer on the restore partition only contains a base system. It'll download any needed components from the 'net.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About 40 minutes or so. I'm assuming a 5400RPM drive, 7200RPM or an SSD would be faster, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

Macbook Pro i7 2.66GHz - USB install (copy image to USB, not install via Snow Leopard).

1st part (downloading additional components) : ~8 minutes

2nd part (actual install) : ~18 minutes